# Sqlite3 - sqlalchemy - flask - InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

during my programming I updated my database format and tried to reupload my data to it and I get the following Line if I try to db.session.commit() to it.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO ingredient__mapping (ratio, drink_id, ingredient_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('20', Drink Gin & Tonic, <Ingredient (transient 1962277680)>)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/rvf5)
```

My Python Code:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email_address = db.Column(db.String(length=50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(length=60), nullable=False)


class Drink(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(length=1024), nullable=False, unique=True)


class Ingredient(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, unique=True)
    percentage = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=True)

class Ingredient_Mapping(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    ratio = db.Column(db.String(length=4), nullable=False)
    drink_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('drink.id'), nullable=False)
    ingredient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ingredient.id'), nullable=False)

    drink = db.relationship('Drink', backref=db.backref('drinks', lazy=True))
    ingredient = db.relationship('Ingredient', backref=db.backref('ingredients', lazy=True))
```

My codelines in Python-Terminal:

```
u1 = User(username='test', email_address='test@gmail.com', password_hash='123456')

d1 = Drink(name='Gin & Tonic', description='ballert hart')

i1 = Ingredient(name='Gin', percentage='37')

i2 = Ingredient(name='Tonic', percentage='0')

im1 = Ingredient_Mapping(drink_id=d1, ratio='20', ingredient_id=i1)

im2 = Ingredient_Mapping(drink_id=d1, ratio='80', ingredient_id=i2)

db.session.add(im1)
db.session.add(im2)
db.session.commit()
```

I can't find wrong variables, but I'm also new to this. After lot Google Search I found references that say I should look at the variables and should be sure that they are correctly (what makes sense, because my "Drink" is recognizable).

EDIT:

I think I figured it out. The ID is not there yet, so the reference <Ingredient (transient 1962277680)> is given. BUT the ID Reference in Ingredient_Mapping ist typed as INTEGER, so it will not take <Ingredient (transient 1962277680)> as an argument. So in that scenario you will probably have to cast your ID query OR commit the ingredients first and then backreference them.

Comment: Try this: `drink = db.relationship('Drink', backref='drinks', lazy=True)`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, but thx for help. I get the same Error.

Comment: You also need to add `d1`, `i1` and `i2` to `db.session`

Comment: Sure? Because Drink 'Gin & Tonic' was integrated and automatically added. In this Docs they say the same [link](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/)